# Different behaviour between two installations of firefox on 22.04 that I would expect to be the same

Tags: permissions, firefox, printing, software-center, snap

I have two machine, lets call them A and B. On A I updated to 22.04 from 20.04, on B I did a fresh install (but retained the user file store). On B Firefox appeared to work normally, on A it couldn't see any printers. A bit of duck-duck-going showed one or two others with the problem and I worked out that the reason was that the application permissions were not set correctly (no access to the cups system) I changed this (using ubuntu software) and all was fine.
However it set me wondering why the original difference? After all on both machines Firefox was a new snap installation. So I also looked at the permissions on the working machine (B), or rather I tried to, because ubuntu software seemed to be completely confused about the state of Firefox. On the one hand it thought it was installed but when you selected the app to have a closer look it only offered the option to install so I couldn't follow the permissions button. So Ubuntu Software seems to think the Firefox is both installed and uninstalled. I am rather loth try the install option and see what happens, as this is on the shared family machine so I don't want to disturb something that seems to be working perfectly without at least having some idea of what might be going on.

Any ideas?

Comment: While I can buy the notion that the original Firefox problem was as a result of the upgrade against the clean install (indeed that was my own opinion. I can't explain the software-centre problem because the machine with the oddity is the one on which I did the clean install. I have since done lists of APT applications and Snap applications and everything looks as one would expect, so I am still puzzled. That said it cannot be said that this is an important problem I just hoped someone might have an idea of what could confuse the software-centre in this way.

Answer (score 2):

- Your first machine was upgraded, the other was a fresh install. With the latter, the system is configured exactly as the developers intended. With the former, configurations of the previous version are propagated. That can explain differences.
- Firefox now only exists as a snap version in the standard Ubuntu software repositories. Still,  a transitional apt package exists, that, when installed, triggers a snap installation. On a fresh system, that transitional package is not installed. In an upgraded system, that transitional package is installed: it replaces the package of the previous version, and indeed, while upgrading, caused the snap version to be installed. This may explain why you see this confusing information about Firefox on one of the systems.

b.t.w., that transitional package can be safely removed (`sudo apt remove firefox`).